# Url settings when deploy GitLab-CE by docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I'd like to know what are correct value for Gitlab-CE docker image's external_url and registry_external_url

Desired final status:

1. Docker running on 192.168.1.21, ports 19022 19080 19443 19050 for ssh, web and container registry.
2. Url for public network access is https://gitlab.k-m.com:21444 (just for example, 80/443 is disabled by ISP)
3. Router will forward connection from port 21444 to SWAG (for acquiring certs and reverse proxy), and SWAG has config like:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name gitlab.*;
include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;
location / {
    proxy_pass https://192.168.1.21:19080;
}
```

Problems I meet:

1. If i set external_url as https one, gitlab will try to acquire certs, that's what i want SWAG to do
2. If i set external_url as 192.168.1.21:19080, i don't how to set port forwarding in docker run
3. Currently, i set localhost:80 for external_url, and set 19080:80 in port forwarding, but

   1. localhost shows everywhere in GitLab's web ui
   2. edit runner it automatically redirect to http://localhost/groups/mygroup/-/runners/1
   3. https://gitlab.k-m.com:21444 shows ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

```
external_url 'http://localhost:80'; registry_external_url 'http://localhost:5050';
```

I believe i misunderstand the meanings of these fields, but i cannot find what is correct in offical document for my scenario, could you help to guide me

Comment: external_url 'https://gitlab.k-m.com:21444'; registry_external_url 'https://registry.k-m.com:21444'; 
letsencrypt['enable'] = false; 
nginx['listen_port'] = 80; 
nginx['listen_https'] = false; 
registry_nginx['listen_https'] = false; 
registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 5050; 
registry['registry_http_addr'] = "localhost:5050"
can make https url work in my home network now, but when i click save for Auto DevOps setting, gitlab will remove my port 21444 in url automatically. And, it's strange i can do docker login with home page url gitlab.xxx instead of registry.xxx